# Delay appending to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript, and i'm just wondering if it's possible to delay appending elements to another element. I have a map, which i've appended points in the form of anchor tags. Once the page loads all of the markers are displayed. I thought it would be a nice feature to add each pointer with a short delay. Here is how I currently append,

```
element = $("<a href='#' class='deskBtn tooltip fancybox' title='" + this.allData[i].Name + "' data-name='" + this.allData[i].UserName + "' data-department='" + this.allData[i].DepartmentName + "'></a>");

$(element).css({
    "top": this.allData[i].DeskYCoord,
        "left": this.allData[i].DeskXCoord
}).appendTo(".map");
```

I tried exposing the setInterval method after the append, however, I was unable to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a timeout, not interval or use delay:

```
$(element).css({
    "top": this.allData[i].DeskYCoord,
        "left": this.allData[i].DeskXCoord
}).delay(2000).queue(function(next){
  $(this).appendTo(".map");
  next();
});
```

Comment: @Wolff, thanks for the suggestion, but would it be possible to load each one with a delay. Currently i'm iterating through an array using a for loop, so each iteration add a pointer to the map. Would it be possible to map a pointer, have a delay of a second, then load the next pointer?

Comment: You could use inside loop something like: `for( var i=0;...;...) {/*code*/.delay((i+1)*1000)...}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the delay() functionality of the jQuery:

```
element = $("<a href='#' class='deskBtn tooltip fancybox' title='" + this.allData[i].Name + "' data-name='" + this.allData[i].UserName + "' data-department='" + this.allData[i].DepartmentName + "'></a>");

  $(element).css({
                "top": this.allData[i].DeskYCoord,
                "left": this.allData[i].DeskXCoord
            })
.delay ( 800, "my-queue" ).queue("my-queue", function (next) {
$(this).appendTo(".map");
next();
```

});

Comment: You need to put appendTo() method in queue

Comment: @A.Wolff thnx, you are right  .. we need a que there so I've updated the code.